# Horizontal Scrolling Banner Isn't Working

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I have created a website in which an entire page scrolls left and right instead of up and down using only HTML and CSS. I have taken that code for another website to create a banner type navigation thing like Polygon's website when the page is viewed for an iPhone or another device with a small screen like that, however I can't understand why in this case the code isn't working, I have spent ages on it and I just cant see the problem. Maybe some fresh pair of eyes will help, here is the code I'm using.

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#cover_menu {
    width: 2560px;
    height: 480px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cover_tile {
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    float: left;
}

    #cover_link {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cover_menu">
<div id="cover_tile">
    <div id="cover_link" class="link_1">hello</div>
    <div id="cover_link" class="link_2">hello</div>
</div>
<div id="cover_tile">
    <div id="cover_link" class="link_3">hello</div>
    <div id="cover_link" class="link_4">hello</div>
</div>
<div id="cover_tile">
    <div id="cover_link" class="link_5">hello</div>
    <div id="cover_link" class="link_6">hello</div>
</div>
<div id="cover_tile">
    <div id="cover_link" class="link_7">hello</div>
    <div id="cover_link" class="link_8">hello</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance, Matt

Comment: I don't get what you mean? its not scrolling right? because you need `overflow-y:hidden;`....? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/67HfZ/)

Comment: So it's working in browser but not on mobile devices? Maybe you should try something with jQuery to filter the client's width and then calculate your banner width. Maybe a js fiddle would help...

Comment: If you go to Polygon.com and then shrink the width of the page down to 728px the banner at the top of the page becomes scrollable (horizontally) as the content is too wide to show on a device with a width of 728px or smaller, I want to replicate this for my website. Does that make more sense? And how can I do that?